# Amount of time to transmit 5GB to USB 2.0?

Tags: networking, performance, file-transfer

How many minutes should it take to transmit 5GB over a USB2.0 (assume 500 Mbps) bandwidth connection? 
How would I figure this out??? When I did the math I came up with 1.3 minutes which Im pretty sure is incorrect. Here is what I did:

5*8000 = 500*60*x

40000=30000x

X = 1.3 Minutes

Answer (score 1):

It should come out to ~1 minute and 21 seconds (+- 1 second).

to do this:

```
500 / 8 //calculate the MBps. 8Mbps to a MBps.
= 62.5

5 * 1024 //calculate what 5GB is in MB
= 5120

5120 / 62.5 //calculate the final seconds amount
= 81.92
```

Comment: Hmm. I get 85.9s from http://www.dslreports.com/calculator?sz=5GB&time=&c2=Calc&speed=500Mbps

Comment: @DavidPostill I did this on paper. my answer could be a little out. just stating what I did

Comment: I guessed you worked it out by hand. I'm trying to work out which one is correct ;)

Comment: I too get 81.92s !

Comment: @RogUE thank god I'm not the only one to get the same calculation

Comment: 500 Mbps = 59.6 MBps according to dslreports. There is the discrepancy.

Comment: @DavidPostill I thought 1 MB = 8 Mb... they must've done something wrong

Comment: Isn't [8Mbit=1Mbyte](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=1+mega+bit%3D&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=BTqWVoieMc6AuwTm-7LIBw#q=8+mega+bit%3D), @DavidPostill that means 1MByte=8.3892Mbit

Answer (score 1):

#### How many minutes should it take to transmit 5GB over a USB2.0 (assume 500 Mbps)

Using the [Bandwidth Calculator](http://www.dslreports.com/calculator):

```
90,071,992.5 ns nanoseconds
87,960.9 ms milliseconds
85.9 s  seconds (default)
1.4 m   minutes
```

[image]